# Found nil в UILabel когда он связан

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

```
class Explain: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var touchid: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ram: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gpu: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cpu: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    func condigure(with product: ProductModel) {
//        self.productImage.image = UIImage(named: product.image)
        self.productName.text = product.title <- error tyt
        self.cpu.text = "CPU: \(product.specs.cpu)"
        self.gpu.text = "GPU: \(product.specs.gpu)"
        self.ram.text = "RAM: \(product.specs.ram)"
        self.display.text = "Display: \(product.specs.screen)"
        
        if (product.other.touchID) {
            self.touchid.text = "Touch ID: Yes"
        }
        else {
            self.touchid.text = "Touch ID: No"
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Почему он выдает unexpectenly found nil while unwrapping ooptional value именно на productName, то есть на объект класса UILabel, хотя я связал их в StoryBoard?

Comment: А точно связали в сториборд? В этом вьюконтроллере все кружочки будут закрашены, если объекты связаны со сториборд.